# Open a specific page on a website

Tags: python, module, python-webbrowser

Using the webbrowser module, I want to open a specific page on last.fm.
It picks a line from a text file then prints it. I want it to add that line at the end of:

```
webbrowser.open('http://www.last.fm/music/')
```

So for example, the random.choice picks example artist. I want example artist to be added at the end of the url correctly. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `urlparse.urljoin` function to build up the full destination URL:

```
import urlparse
import webbrowser

artist_name = 'virt' 
url = urlparse.urljoin('http://www.last.fm/music/', artist_name)

# Will open http://www.last.fm/music/virt in your browser.
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: Just for python 3 folks, it's `import urllib.parse` and `urllib.parse.urljoin` to join the url